# How do I update a document property's sub-property?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update an object or create it if it doesn't exist. But more specifically, I want to update a nested property with a dynamic property name.

```
let $set = {
  $set: {
    dirs: {},
    path: subPath
  }
};
$set.$set.dirs[dir] = true;
promises.push(this.db.collection("dir").update(
  { path: subPath },
  $set,
  { upsert: true }
).catch(err => {
  console.log("err", err)
}));
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't just append the property, it overwrites the `dirs` property with a single child. The resulting document structure is like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ede79cb275bd377d80efac3"),
    "path" : "E:\\options-data\\AAPL\\2004",
    "dirs" : {
        "01" : true
    }
}
```

dirs will never have more than one property this way. If I have to actually load the document first to check the dirs and update them accordingly, that would be extremely slow considering I need to do this operation hundreds of millions of times.

Comment: how does your document structure looks like?

Comment: @Ifaruki I edited to add that. Also I just found the solution. I can make the "dirs" prop an array and use `addToSet` :D

Comment: i have edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var property = "test";
promises.push(this.db.collection("dir").update(
  { path: subPath },
  { $set: {
       [`dirs.${property}`]: true 
     } 
  },
  { upsert: true }
).catch(err => {
  console.log("err", err)
}));
```